# Docker compose env variables not used in Springboot application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to pull in some environment variables I placed in docker-compose to my application.yml:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
some-api:
        depends_on:
            - mysql-database
        build: 
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample_database?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
            - MYSQL_PORT=3306
            - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=somepassword
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${MYSQL_URL}
    username: ${MYSQL_USERNAME}
    password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine
WORKDIR /build
COPY ./pom.xml ./
COPY ./src ./src/
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 ./build/target/SampleApp-0.1.0.jar ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "SampleApp-0.1.0.jar"]
```

But I'm getting this error message in the logs when I do a docker-compose up:

**Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${MYSQL_URL}**

I'm guessing that the env variables are not being passed properly to the springboot containerized app.
Does anyone know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Spotted the error in the mysql URL, it shouldn't be localhost, but the name of the db service in docker-compose:

```
- MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://<my-db-service>:3306/some_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow @exe-apps! Can you share your Dockerfile? The problem could be on your `CMD` and/or `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: @jmaitrehenry thank you! I've added the dockerfile in the question.

Comment: Hi @exe-apps , did you manage to solve this issue?